# Getting WGS84 height of a given place mark - Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, wgs84

Setting manually a place mark for a given location or obtaining the coordinates via Google Earth search yields the (Long,Lat) WGS84 coordinates.
I'm fully aware of map is a 2D concept, yet is there a possibility for getting the WGS84 height of a given location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mousing over a location shows the elevation at the bottom of the screen, along with lat/lon.

There's also the Elevation Profile feature: https://support.google.com/earth/answer/181393?hl=en